# Why can't I save a PDF questionnaire's result?

Tags: pdf

There's a PDF questionnaire with radio buttons and textboxes which I filled out on the web.

When I'm trying to download this document, I get an empty local questionnaire without any results. How can I save it properly?

This is the file:

> http://www.developer.nokia.com/Distribute/App_Declaration_Document_v2.4.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a **Password Protected**
OR
On PDF settings, it might be restricted to save the filled data.

As per your updated URL,

It is working as expected. There is no issue while saving.

Comment: question was updated

Comment: updated my answer. It is working as expected. There is no issue while saving.

Comment: this is strange, when I save it, the page is clear - without answers

Comment: Which version of Acrobat are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I was opening it with SumatraPDF, then I tried Acrobat